# SMS link to app using Branch.io

Tags: android, sms, deep-linking, branch.io

I'm trying to set a link that will send an SMS message with a branch link. My Android phone isn't receiving the message.

this is the code I'm using to call the SMS:

```
public void shareLightfieldsGame() {
    Log.i("BRANCH", "shareLightfieldsGame");
    JSONObject params = new JSONObject();
    try {
        params.put("referringUsername", "Mario");
        params.put("referringUserId", "1234");
    } catch (JSONException ex) {}

    Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getShortUrl("SMS", "share", null, params, new Branch.BranchLinkCreateListener() {

    @Override 
    public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
            Log.i("BRANCH", "ERROR=" + error);
            Log.i("BRANCH", "URL=" + url);
        }
    });
}
```

SDK seems properly initialized, but my SMS does not show up on Android Samsung Galaxy S3 Mini.
It’s weird ! Are you sure this code should pop SMS’s messages on android? I might have forgotten something, or uppercase issue maybe?

Answer (score 0):

If you are looking to pop up the SMS with that code snippet, it needs to be embedded into more code that initiates the SMS call.

Please check out our [Android sample app](https://github.com/BranchMetrics/Branchster-Android/blob/master/src/io/branch/branchster/MonsterViewerActivity.java#L127) which does this for SMS, Email, Facebook and Twitter. Here's the line of code where we call the SMS:

```
// Share via SMS.
cmdMessage.setOnClickListener(new OnClickListener() {

    @Override
    public void onClick(View v) {
        Branch.getInstance(getApplicationContext()).getContentUrl("sms", prepareBranchDict(), new BranchLinkCreateListener() {

            @Override
            public void onLinkCreate(String url, BranchError error) {
                Uri uri = Uri.parse("smsto:");
                Intent intent = new Intent(Intent.ACTION_SENDTO, uri);
                intent.putExtra("sms_body", "Check out my Branchster named " + monsterName + " at " + url);
                startActivity(intent);
            }
        });
    }
});
```

You may also need to make sure that you have properly initialized the Branch session prior to calling getShortUrl. Please see [this section](https://dev.branch.io/recipes/quickstart_guide/android/#starting-a-branch-session?bmp=so-ac) of the guide to make it happen.

Let me know if this helps!

Comment: It's working like a charm, thank you guys @ Branch.io